# Extract data from an HTML table on a Web page into Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer

I need some help with taking data from website using vba. I have table in excel with etf ticker, link and price and using vba I try to take close price of yesterday from each link but the problem is that I am not sure what to write at this place "HTMLDoc.getElementById("???")". I can't find any ID from that website html code, hope you can help me with that.

website example: https://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/en/etf/amundi-prime-global-ucits-etf-dr-c/price-history/historical-prices-and-volumes

my code:

```
Sub GetETFPrices()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim ETFLink As String
    Dim ETFPrice As String
    Dim i As Long

    ' Loop through each row in the table
    For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        ETFLink = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value ' Get link from column 2
        
        ' Opening the link in Internet Explorer
        IE.Navigate ETFLink

        
        Do While IE.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

        ' Get the ETF price element from the HTML document
        Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
        Set ETFRow = HTMLDoc.getElementById("???").Rows(HTMLDoc.getElementById("???").Rows.Length - 1)
        ETFPrice = ETFRow.Cells(3).innerText

        ' Updating the price column in Excel sheet
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value = ETFPrice
    Next i

    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the use of Internet Explorer a requirement?

Comment: not a requirement, but other internet apps not really working on my vba, probably some settings should be added, thus I chosed what was working in this case.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into the answer I provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to use Internet Explorer, I would suggest to use [Selenium](https://codingislove.com/browser-automation-in-excel-selenium/) which is compatible with Chrome (and FireFox).

Now, looking at the page you linked, this is the case where your data is inside a table and there is no `id` attribute that will allow you to target a specific cell. Because of that, I would suggest to import the whole table from the page in Excel and then you can more easily navigate to find the data point you are interested in.

You could use this approach for instance:

```vb
Sub ImportHtmlTable()

    'Initialize Selenium
    Dim bot As WebDriver
    Set bot = New WebDriver
    
    bot.Start "chrome", "YourUrl"
    bot.Get "/"
    DoEvents

    Dim Tables As WebElements
    Set Tables = bot.FindElementsByTag("table")

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("YourWorkbookName")
    HtmlTablesToRange Tables, wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    
    bot.Close
    Set bot = Nothing

End Sub

'Inspired by code from: https://www.vba-market.com/
Sub HtmlTablesToRange(Tables As WebElements, Destination As Range)

    Destination.CurrentRegion.ClearContents

    Dim tb As WebElement
    Dim ths As WebElements 'Headers    (th)
    Dim trs As WebElements 'Rows       (tr)
    Dim tds As WebElements 'Data cells (td)
    
    For Each tb In Tables
    
        Dim theads As WebElements
        Set theads = tb.FindElementsByTag("thead")
        Dim thead As WebElement
        For Each thead In theads
            Set trs = thead.FindElementsByTag("tr")
            Dim tr As WebElement
            For Each tr In trs
                Set ths = tr.FindElementsByTag("th")
                Dim y As Long, z As Long
                y = 0 ' Resets back to first column
                Dim th As WebElement
                For Each th In ths
                    Destination.Offset(z, y).Value = th.text
                    y = y + 1
                Next th
                z = z + 1
            Next tr
        Next thead
 
        Dim tbodys As WebElements
        Set tbodys = tb.FindElementsByTag("tbody")
        Dim tbody As WebElement
        For Each tbody In tbodys
            Set trs = tbody.FindElementsByTag("tr")
            For Each tr In trs
                Set tds = tr.FindElementsByTag("td")
                y = 0 ' Resets back to first column
                Dim td As WebElement
                For Each td In tds
                    Destination.Offset(z, y).Value = td.text
                    y = y + 1
                Next td
                z = z + 1
            Next tr
        Next tbody
        z = z + 1
    Next tb

End Sub
```

If you need to improve performance, you can also turn off `Application.ScreenUpdating` during the execution of the code.

Note that you might need to [update the Chrome driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) usually located in C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic

Disclaimer: Always make sure that you are allowed to gather data from the website you are interested in.