# Scraping data from webpage after pressing a button that runs JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to make a simple VBA module in Excel that scrapes data from javascript webpage after clicking one button. I'm stuck with navigating inside the opened webpage in IE. After IE opens the webpage, I want to click on the buttton selected on the image below and after page load to srcape table to my excel sheeet.
[image]

Here is my current code

```
Sub test()
Dim IE As Object

WebAddress = "http://webpage.test/"


  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate WebAddress
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
  IE.document.getElementById("javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnDolasci','')")(0).Click
  'IE.Navigate "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnDolasci','')"

  While IE.busy
    DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
  Wend

  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 4))

  'IE.Document.getElementById("Response_123").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the HTML structure of the part of the page with the table you are interested in (after you clicked on that button)? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76508473/edit) your question to provide this information.

Comment: You've put the href instead of the id in your `GetElementById`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest avoiding using Internet Explorer (IE) for that task especially when JavaScript is involved. The last update to IE was in 2013 and with how fast things more on the web, there is a non-negligible chance that IE won't support the JS features you need to run the script that loads the data (look at all those red boxes for IE 11 in [this compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)).

Instead, I would suggest using [Selenium](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) which is compatible with modern browsers such as Chrome, Edge and Firefox.

### An example using the Chrome WebDriver

Let's say you want to load the data from the table in this simplified page:
https://jsfiddle.net/decimalturn/ux45vm7e/12/

There is only an anchor "button" that runs JS code that will load the data table on the page.

[image]

To automate this process, you could get to click and load the data using this code:

```vb
Sub ClickAndLoadData()

    'Initialize Selenium
    Dim bot As Selenium.WebDriver
    Set bot = New Selenium.WebDriver
    
    bot.Start "chrome", "https://jsfiddle.net/ux45vm7e/12/"
    bot.Get "/"
    DoEvents
    
    'Here we need to switch to the iframe where our webpage is
    'If it was a real webpage, you would not need this step
    bot.SwitchToFrame bot.FindElementByCss("[name='result']")

    Dim anchor As WebElement
    Set anchor = bot.FindElementById("123")
    anchor.Click
    
    DoEvents
    
    'Get all tables on the page
    Dim Tables As WebElements
    Set Tables = bot.FindElementsByTag("table")

    'Creae a new workbook to save the output
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        'Transfer the content of all tables on page to a range
        HtmlTablesToRange Tables, wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
    bot.Close
    Set bot = Nothing

End Sub

'Inspired by code from: https://www.vba-market.com/
Sub HtmlTablesToRange(Tables As WebElements, Destination As Range)

    Destination.CurrentRegion.ClearContents

    Dim tb As WebElement
    Dim ths As WebElements 'Headers    (th)
    Dim trs As WebElements 'Rows       (tr)
    Dim tds As WebElements 'Data cells (td)
    
    For Each tb In Tables
    
        Dim theads As WebElements
        Set theads = tb.FindElementsByTag("thead")
        Dim thead As WebElement
        For Each thead In theads
            Set trs = thead.FindElementsByTag("tr")
            Dim tr As WebElement
            For Each tr In trs
                Set ths = tr.FindElementsByTag("th")
                Dim y As Long, z As Long
                y = 0 ' Resets back to first column
                Dim th As WebElement
                For Each th In ths
                    Destination.Offset(z, y).Value = th.text
                    y = y + 1
                Next th
                z = z + 1
            Next tr
        Next thead
 
        Dim tbodys As WebElements
        Set tbodys = tb.FindElementsByTag("tbody")
        Dim tbody As WebElement
        For Each tbody In tbodys
            Set trs = tbody.FindElementsByTag("tr")
            For Each tr In trs
                Set tds = tr.FindElementsByTag("td")
                y = 0 ' Resets back to first column
                Dim td As WebElement
                For Each td In tds
                    Destination.Offset(z, y).Value = td.text
                    y = y + 1
                Next td
                z = z + 1
            Next tr
        Next tbody
        z = z + 1
    Next tb

End Sub
```

Note the use of `DoEvents` which allows to return the control to the OS such that loading/changes on the page are processed before continuing.

Note also the use of the procedure `HtmlTablesToRange` which that I took from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76066069/5958842).